# Insert javascript file in aspx file, Literal?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to insert a seperate javascript file in a aspx file. What's the best way to insert a javscript file?

I've tried

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<script type="text/javascript" src="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style%20Library/js/test.js %>" ></script>' />
```

Why I'm doing this inside a aspx file is that I only have to run this code in display mode:

```
<PublishingWebConrols:EditModePanel ID="Fancyboxdisplay" runat="server" PageDisplayMode="Display">
     <asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<script type="text/javascript" src="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style%20Library/js/test.js %>" ></script>' />
</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
```

**Solution**
Use asp literal only to render the script src

```
<PublishingWebConrols:EditModePanel ID="Fancyboxdisplay" runat="server" PageDisplayMode="Display">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="<asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style%20Library/js/test.js %>/>" ></script>' 
</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<PublishingWebConrols:EditModePanel ID="Fancyboxdisplay" runat="server" PageDisplayMode="Display">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style%20Library/js/test.js %>/>" ></script>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the literal text tag without a server-side control wrapper, as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style%20Library/js/test.js %>"></script>
```